# Human and fox offspring in Shinto?

Tags: mythical-creatures, japanese, shinto

When a [kitsune](http://www.mythicalcreaturesguide.com/page/Kitsune) take human form and marries a human, they often have children. *When* the offspring are human, they inherit abilities (special physical or supernatural qualities). These in turn are passed to their children.

The word choice makes me think that the offspring aren't always human. Is there a story to corroborate my suspicions?
or...
It there a Shinto Myth in which a kitsune-wife give birth to something other than a human?

Comment: Abe no Seimei is a famous supposed descendant of a Kitsune mother. He gained incredible magical abilities and there is an interesting pair of movies based on his life. I actually haven't heard of anything other than a human kitsune pair bond, but that doesn't mean there isn't.